# Using WP Category Permalink plugin with Yoast Breadcrumb

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using a wordpress plugin called [WP Category Permalink](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/) which allows you to select a specific category to use as the permalink on a post if there are a number of categories associated with a post.

The plugin works great and shows the url I want with the parent category I've selected, however i'm also using the breadcrumb facility provided in the Yoast SEO plugin and i'd like the breadcrumb to follow the same permalink structure as determined by the [WP Category Permalink](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/) plugin. The breadcrumb just uses the default display of the parent category and displays the first one in alphabetical order.

After looking on the support section of the Category Permalink plugin it seems someone had the same idea and offers the following code which he has used with another breadcrumb plugin:

```
add_filter("get_the_categories","chr_primary_category");
function chr_primary_category($cats){
    global $post;
    $chr_catmeta = get_post_meta($post->ID,"_category_permalink",true);
    if($chr_catmeta == "") { 
        return $cats; // save our energy if there's no primary category set
    }
    $specialcat = "";
    foreach($cats as $key=>$cat){
        if($cat->term_id == $chr_catmeta){
            $specialcat = $cat;
            unset($cats[$key]);
        }
    }
    if($specialcat != ""){
        $cats = array_merge(array($specialcat),$cats); // merge it all back together, with our special category first
    }
    return $cats;
}
```

But I have no idea how to utilise this so was hoping someone had some ideas or had tried something similar. I can't even seem to echo the chr_primary_category function array without an error being thrown.

Thanks

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in localhost etc...`

Comment: Maybe there is another filter on same action.  If you have a debugger you can break the code on entry and set a watch for $cats to see if it is indeed an array.